# Php 7.0 Armbian,how i can FIX Mysqli?

Tags: php, ubuntu, mysqli, orange-pi, armbian

```
root@orangepilite:~# php -e 'phpInfo();' | grep -i mysqli
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_connect in Unknown on line 0
root@orangepilite:~# ^C

root@orangepilite:~# apt-get install php-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@orangepilite:~#
```

How i can enable and fix MYSQLI?
PhpAdmin error [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8AmK.png)

Comment: try to restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @jagad89 - Looking at the question, it looks like they are using PHP from the command line so restarting Apache won't make any difference.

Comment: @jagad89, already restarted, did not help

Comment: Did you installed multiple php version ?

Comment: you should run `php -v` and a php page with `<?php phpinfo();`, both version should be match. Many times php-cli version and php version active with apache differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix by

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so
```

in php.ini